# django unable to filter for more than one term

Tags: django, filter, django-views

```
design_list = Design.objects.filter(tags__tag__contains='jewellery')
```

If I add a filter term (below), it returns 'keyword argument repeated'

```
design_list = Design.objects.filter(tags__tag__contains='jewellery', tags__tag__contains='gadget')
```

How do I add further terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) in order to make an `OR` query:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Design.objects.filter(Q(tags__tag__contains = "jewellery") | Q(tags__tag__contains = "gadget"))
```

Comment: You can also use __in like so `tags__tag__contains__in=['jewellery', 'gadget']`